# Seeking Example Delphi Prism ASP.Net Application using SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-applications, oxygene

I'm an ASP.NET virgin and want to try creating an ASP.Net Application using SQL Server at the back end.

I can't locate a single example application or code for doing this.  Anyone have any pointers?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Delphi Prism is just the language and connecting to a SQL database is exactly the same way you would do so C#. I would look for a C# example on doing so and convert the syntax to Delphi (very easy to do). If you plan on using Delphi Prism you will spend a lot of time converting C# syntax examples to Delphi so you should get some practice.